# best option for wire or cable to accessory building…

Tags: electrical, wiring

Located in Orlando, FL. Running power to an accessory structure from primary home. 125Amp in non-metallic pvc conduit buried 24” 300’ to structure. The building is 1000sf and has laundry room with washer/dryer, kitchen possibly in the future (the reason I want 125A service is to never need to upgrade), on demand propane water heater, 1 bed, 1 bath, 2.5ton AC unit with condenser and handler.

Running several wire calculators to keep around the recommended although I understand not required 3% in drop is giving me a pretty big and costly cable.

Trying to save money and handle the underground and service myself then learn as I go.

Just today I was recommended to go with (2) 2 aught, (1) 1 aught for neutral, and #2 for the ground.

Any help would be appreciated as I just want to do it the right way one time and the different specs of wire are a bit confusing to a novice.

Comment: if the cost is the issue, look for Aluminum wires

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want aluminum feeder wire, nothing wrong with aluminum at these large sizes.  It's attaching to lugs which are made of aluminum, which lets all the air out of the arguments against it.  They are based on misconceptions anyway.

Wire sizes go line this:

```
 8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0-00-000-0000
```

Those 0's, we call them e.g. 00 is called 2/0 or "two-ought".   So let's answer your question about sizing.

### Option 1: Declare it a 120A feeder.

The "normal" thing we do in an application like yours is simply declare the circuit to be 120A.    That is the exact capacity of 1/0 aluminum wire.  **Your Load Calculation on that subpanel cannot exceed 120A**.  *Since 120A breakers are not made, under the feeder rules you are allowed to enlarge to the next larger breaker size available, 125A*. But it is still a 120A circuit.

So in this case, your minimum wire sizes are AWG 1/0, 1/0, 1/0 and #4 aluminum for the 2 hots, neutral and ground.

You are concerned with voltage drop, and at 300 feet, I agree. So let's enlarge the hot conductors to 2/0.  Should you also enlarge the neutral?  Well you don't have to, since this is a 120A circuit that only requires 1/0.

However, since you are enlarging the hots, you must enlarge the ground wire also *in proportion*.  The AWG numbers are logarithmic/exponential, so since you went -1 wire size you must -1 ground size. #3 aluminum doesn't exist so it'll be #2 aluminum ground.

So for our 120A feeder we choose 2/0, 2/0, 1/0 and #2 wires.

### Option 2: Declare it a 125A feeder.

1/0 aluminum is only 120A and is not sufficient for 125A feeder.  Thus, 2/0 aluminum is mandatory *since you declared it to be 125A*.

Generally, residential rules *do not* allow a reduction in neutral size.  So reducing the neutral to 1/0 is a no-go since it is a 125A circuit.  You can talk to your AHJ about a variance/waiver, but at the least they'll need to see your supporting math per NEC Article 220.

Since we're at the same wire size we arrived at in option 1, we don't need a "bump" for voltage drop.  "Tomayto, tomahto".  Thus we are able to stick with the minimum wire size.

Since we did not enlarge the conductors beyond minimum, we don't need to enlarge the ground either.  #4 ground will suffice.

Thus for 125A our wires are 2/0, 2/0, 2/0 and #4.

Comment: Thank you Harper. Is it best to run each of the 4 wires individually or will a supply house create a cable with the 2/0-2/0-1/0-#6? Trying to keep the conduit size as minimal as possible after seeing prices. 

I see options online but not certain exactly what to order

Comment: With conduit, you do *not* want the wires assembled into a cable as that will make it harder to pull and can increase the necessary conduit size. Online calculator shows 1-1/2" PVC required.

Comment: Thank you manassehkatz. I appreciate it

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  thank you. Does this spec look correct to you regarding wire to order? 

Ground:
4 AWG XHHW ALUMINUM CABLE
600V (X325)
Color: Green

(X2) Phase wire:
2/0 AWG XHHW ALUMINUM
CABLE 600V (X325)
Color. Black.
Neutral wire:
1/0 AWG XHHW ALUMINUM
CABLE 600V (X325)
Color: Black

Comment: @Kevin Has your AHJ authorized a 1/0 neutral on a 12***5***A circuit?  You either have to enlarge the neutral to 2/0.... or declare the circuit to be 120A instead of 125A and enlarge the ground to #3 or #2.  For reasons explained in my answer edit.  Other than that it looks great.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica perfect…so I’ll just order (3) 2/0 AWG XHHW Aluminum Cable 600V and the (1) 4 AWG XHHW Aluminum Cable for the ground. Thank you for your help!

Comment: At these sizes, you might be better off for the 2/0 ordering an entire 1000' spool (about 100' more than you need) - you may get a better deal than 3 x 300' cut to order because the vendor doesn't have to actually *do anything* except put it on the truck. And for the ground then order a few extra feet - better to pay for 330' (or whatever) than to pay for 300' and find you are 3 feet short...

Comment: If you order a big spool, be sure to invest in a proper cutter to trim it to length. Bolt cutters _will_ cut the stuff, but will mangle then ends, you want a proper wire cutter to give you a nice clean cut.

Comment: I just reorganized the answer to better explain what the heck is going on with neutral/ground sizing.   I carry a mini hacksaw in my electrical toolbox for cutting EMT, I just use that on big wire.